# Android layout border hiding background corners

Tags: android, android-layout

I've designed a pop-up window in my app and used the following shape drawable as my border:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle">
    <corners android:radius="20dp"/>
    <padding android:left="20dp" android:right="20dp" android:top="10dp" android:bottom="20dp"/>
    <solid android:color="@android:color/holo_green_light"/>
    <stroke android:color="@android:color/black" android:width="2dp"/>
</shape>
```

And this is what my layout XML looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".popChart"
    android:background="@drawable/customborder"
    >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/closeIcon"
        android:layout_width="25dp"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:src="@drawable/close" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:paddingTop="30dp">

        <com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.LineChart
            android:id="@+id/lineC"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@android:color/white"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="8dp" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

The border is fine but the white corners of the this drawable background are still visible:

[image]

Since the background I have behind this popup is not a solid color, the white corners stand out and look bad. Is there a way to get rid of them or make them transparent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely the issue is that your theme has a white background color for windows. You'll need to define a new theme:

```
<style name="customStyle" parent="@android:style/Theme.Dialog">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
</style>
```

Then apply it to your window:

```
new PopupWindow(new ContextThemeWrapper(context, R.style.customStyle)))
// Set your window size and focusable if needed...
```

Comment: I'm not using the PopupWindow class to do this, I'm just setting the layout width and height using this function: getWindow().setLayout((int) (width*0.9),(int)(height*0.6));

Can I modify the default theme to do that directly?

Comment: Yup, just expect that all your windows will have transparent backgrounds. So your layouts will need to set them as needed.